# How does a Voice Box guitar effect work?

Tags: technique

I heard an old Barnstorm album where Joe Walsh made his guitar talk. How did he do that?

Comment: You might also check out what is probably the most famous example: https://youtu.be/V9Yq5m9eLIQ

Comment: Just realised this has a dupe - [How does The Talkbox work?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/how-does-the-talkbox-work) & another with a pic of Frampton's actual talk box from Comes Alive - https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48809/air-tube-to-change-the-sound-of-guitar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually unbelievably simple.

The guitar signal feeds to an on-stage box, which contains a small speaker. A hollow plastic tube comes from that box up to the performer's mouth.
The performer puts the end of the tube in his mouth & can shape the signal straight into his vocal mic.